# How to test for vector initialization success/failure in C++

Tags: c++, stl, error-handling, initialization

I have a C++ class with `vector<float>` members which are initialized in the constructor to a size determined by one of the constructor's arguments.

```
summingBuffer = vector<float>(requiredSize);
```

How do I check whether the vector constructor has successfully allocated the the required space?  The instance vars aren't pointers (should they be?) so `if (NULL==myVector)` doesn't work. Does `vector` throw an exception on allocation error?  How about checking `.size()` afterwards?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector constructor will raise `bad_alloc` if it couldn't allocate enough storage, no need for extra checks.

Using pointers is not a good idea if you don't absolutely need them.

Also, looks like you could initialize your vectors directly rather than how you're doing it by using your constructor's initializer list. Something like:

```
struct foo {
  std::vector<float> things;

  foo(int vsize) : things(vsize) {
    // rest of constructor code
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and code snippet.  In that example, will the bad_alloc exception just bubble up to the line of client code invoking foo's constructor?  Also, I was lead to believe by the last sentence on this FAQ question that the STL didn't handle errors in its constructors: http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.17  Nor could I find a decent reference online.  Do you know of any?

Comment: `bad_alloc` will propagate until it's caught (or causes your program to die). You're mis-reading that line in the FQA. It says the STL doesn't deal with errors in constructors by using exceptions, not that the STL doesn't deal with exceptions thrown by constructors. (And generally, be careful with the information you read on the FQA.  I'm not saying it's wrong, but it's very opinionated.)

Answer (score 4):

Default allocator throws `std::bad_alloc` on failed allocation, just like `new T` does. So, no, no size checking is necessary. This isn't C.